# Store a polygon in a field using GeoDjango and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, geodjango

I am currently working on a project that involves storing polygons in a GeoDjango field. I am using Google Maps to draw the polygons, but I am encountering an error when I try to save them. The error message is

> django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKTReader_read_r

Specifically, I am able to save polygons in this format:
`'POLYGON ((66.98106581568717 30.179605233947377,66.97718849521253 30.176396998548686,66.98106581568717 30.179605233947377))'`,
but I am unable to save polygons in this format:
`'POLYGON((66.98707396388053 30.176192128250534,66.98281566332209 30.17265923177731,66.9889954728924 30.17028474252859))'`.

How can I modify the format of the polygon so that it can be saved in the GeoDjango field without encountering the error message?

Comment: Neither of those strings is valid Well-Known Text. A Polygon must have at least four vertices, with the first and last being the same location.

Comment: @Vince So how to modify the polygon format to meet the requirements for a valid Well-Known Text format ?

Can you provide an example of a valid Well-Known Text format for a polygon with four or more vertices?
Are there any you recommend for converting a polygon to a valid Well-Known Text format because i am drawing polygon on "google map using google map api".?
Are there any other common mistakes or issues to be aware of when working with Well-Known Text formats and polygons in GeoDjango?

Comment: @Vince
Please note that I am able to save a polygon with three vertices (points) in the format by drawing it in the admin panel without encountering any errors. The first example I provided was drawn in the admin panel.

Comment: The first example is a degenerate polygon (a line that doubles back on itself). The second one fails because it does not close. Neither is a valid Polygon, but the second is treated as an error. Note that it's the same *format*, but different *values* in that format.  WKT is vague on orientation, but exterior rings generally wrap counterclockwise. The second would likely not fail if the first vertex were repeated as the fourth vertex.